# Problem with the __str__ method

Tags: python

This is my script:

```
import math
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def ___str___(self):
        return "{0}, {1}".format(self.x, self.y)

    @classmethod
    def vectorPoints(cls, p1, p2):
        a = p2[0] - p1[0]
        b = p2[1] - p1[1]
        return Vector(a, b)

A = (1,5)
B = (2,7)
vectAB = Vector.vectorPoints(A, B)
print(vectAB)
vect = Vector(1, 0)
print(vect)
```

When I run this script I get:

```
<__main__.Vector object at 0x00FD5ED0>
<__main__.Vector object at 0x00FD5FF0>
```

Apparently the `__str__` method isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 10):

The method name should be `__str__` (2 underscores surrounding), not `___str___` (3 underscores surrounding).

Answer (score 3):

You are using three underscores (`_`) instead of the normal two.